# Center <a href> text vertically inside undefined height <li>

Tags: html, css, centering, image-gallery

I'm trying to make responsive proportionally rectangles for my gallery, which was working, but i can't centering text vertically. I don't understand how to  proportionally resize  centering text. Any help or advice will be appreciated.
Thanks.

```
#container{
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}

#MyList li{
    float: left;
    background-image: url(../images/bardiches.png);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center; 
}

#MyList a{
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 100%;

    display: block;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.0);

    transition: background-color 500ms ease-out;
}

#MyList a:hover{
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.95);
}
```

Desktop/Tablet Styles

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px){
    #container{
        width:80%;
    }

    #MyList li{
        width:46%;
        margin-bottom:50px;
        margin-left: 2%;
        margin-right: 2%;
    }

    #MyList li:nth-child(4n){
        margin-right:0px;
    }

    #MyList a{
        height:100%;
        padding-bottom: 55%;
    }
}
```

html

```
<div id="container">
    <ul id="MyList">
        <li>
           <a href="#"> 
              Bardiches
           </a>
        </li>
        <li>
           <a href="#"> 
              Bardiches
           </a>
        </li>
        <li>
           <a href="#"> 
              Bardiches
           </a>
        </li>
        <li>
           <a href="#"> 
              Bardiches
           </a>
        </li>
        <li>
           <a href="#"> 
              Bardiches
           </a>
        </li>
        <li>
           <a href="#"> 
              Bardiches
           </a>
        </li>

    </ul>
</div>
```

My current test site below:-

http://benson.graphics/test/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try wrapping the text inside span tags like this and add the following CSS rules. It will work in multi lines text too. Hope this will help you.

```
<a href="#">
    <span>Bardiches</span>
</a>

#MyList a {
    position: relative;
}

#MyList a span {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 0;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: This does seem to work, only issue is implementing a second line with that span.How would you do accomplish this, so that the second line can be styled seperately?

Comment: Multiple span tags inside the same a tag wont work(in this situation). Could you try long text inside the same span tag. It will work as expected.

Comment: If you want the second line to be styled separately wrap it inside any other html tags and apply seperate CSS for it.

Answer (score 0):

```
#MyList li {
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  margin-left: 2%;
  margin-right: 2%;
  position: relative;
  width: 46%;
}
#MyList a span {
  bottom: 0;
  height: 5%;
  left: 0;
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Just put 'span' tag between all 'a' tag

Answer (score 0):

There is a padding-bottom rule of 55% which is in all your anchor tags contained in your li tags. Take this out..because this will display that long white space after your span with text

You can divide this padding space equally top and bottom

```
#MyList a{
padding-bottom: 27.5% !important;
padding-top: 27.5% !important;;
}
```

Snippet

```css
 #MyList a{
    padding-bottom: 27.5% !important;
    padding-top: 27.5% !important;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
  <title>Title</title>
  <link href="css/reset.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <link href="http://benson.graphics/test/css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mobile.custom.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <section>
    <div id="container">
      <ul id="MyList">
        <li>
          <a href="#"> 
                            Bardiches
                        </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">
            <span class="title">
                                Bardiches
                            </span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">
            <span class="title">
                                Bardiches
                            </span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">
            <span class="title">
                                Bardiches
                            </span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">
            <span class="title">
                                Bardiches
                            </span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">
            <span class="title">
                                Bardiches
                            </span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">
            <span class="title">
                                Bardiches
                            </span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">
            <span class="title">
                                Bardiches
                            </span>
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </section>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/custom_behaviors.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This does work, but I'm curious if it will susceptible to further text changes. For example, if I added a second line of text or increased the current line's size, would that expand the tile's height?

Comment: Yes...since you are using height in percentage! I would go using height in pixels..but I believe that's how you would like to design these boxes?

Comment: That's correct, so this may not be the optimal solution for my problem. Thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way using using flex:

Just change the definition of the following block in CSS:

```
#container li {
   width: 46%;
   margin-bottom: 50px;
   margin-left: 2%;
   margin-right: 2%;
   height: 200px;
   display: flex;
   justify-content: space-around;
   flex-direction: column;
}
```

I had to add a height tag for my tests but it might be bec of the pic I used.

Comment: Forgot to add, these should be removed also in @media query:   #MyList a {height: 100%; padding-bottom: 55%; }